# Possibility of changing an index to an array in a constructor

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, file, indexing

I have this constructor that reads from a file, and as you can see I have used index a couple of times right after the `Random rand = new Random();` statement. Is there any way possible to **change these indexes into an array**?

Thank you in advance!

```
private static void MensSingle(int numPlayers)
{
        //Players
        var f = new ReadFile(@"C:\Path.txt");
        f.LoadPlayers(100,GenderType.Male);
        List<Player> totalPlayers = f.playerListTxt;
        List<Player> myPlayers = new List<Player>();
        int myTotalPlayers = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int playerIndex = rand.Next(1, myTotalPlayers);
            Player p = totalPlayers[playerIndex - 1];
            myPlayers.Add(p);
            totalPlayers.Remove(totalPlayers[playerIndex - 1]);
            myTotalPlayers -= 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: what you mean by *change these indexes into an array?*?

Comment: I mean is it possible to make these indexes an array (string array for example) instead, or just change them so that they are not indexes

Comment: You meant to say, you want to get all possible random values for the seed you are providing in one go without looping through and calling `Next()`?

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. Anyway as a side note: indexes in C# or zero based - [0-len-1]. Random max value are exclusive, meaning you get a number between [min_val, max_val-1].  Meaning it's enough for you to do: `Player p = totalPlayers[rand.Next(0, myTotalPlayers)];`

Comment: Also you are re-seeding the `Random` every iteration. You should seed it once before the loop.

Comment: Try defining what exactly you mean when you say "index", because under the context of what people generally understand an index and an array to be, your question makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
Random r = new Random();
int maxPlayerCount = 100;
int myPlayerCount = 10;
List<int> players = Enumerable.Range(1, maxPlayerCount).ToList();
List<int> myPlayers = Enumerable.Range(1, myPlayerCount)
                           .Select(i => players.Skip(r.Next(1, players.Count)).First())
                           .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

you want to Shuffle your list as what i understand

Items = Items.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToList();

Comment: Use `Random` for randomizing operations. `Guid` is guaranteed to be unique, not random.